# recursively change file names in directories

Tags: python, recursion

Starting with a source directory;

<  C:/Users/Public/Env Defense/Projects/1_Earnings Calls/Quarterly Earnings Calls/1_IOUs by Quarter/2013 Q1/AAA Done/

there are multiple subdirectories within the source directory; for example

< /Users/Public/Env Defense/Projects/1_Earnings Calls/Quarterly Earnings Calls/1_IOUs by Quarter/2013 Q1/AAA Done/AEP

/Users/Public/Env Defense/Projects/1_Earnings Calls/Quarterly Earnings Calls/1_IOUs by Quarter/2013 Q1/AAA DONE/Allete

Within each subdirectory are multiple  files with common words in the names such as;

*2013 Q1 AEP Earnings Call Transcript.txt

*2013 Q1 AEP Earnings Call Transcript.txt

*2013 Q1 ALLETE Earnings Call Transcript.docx

*2013 Q1 AEP Earnings Call Presentation.pdf'

I am writing a script to walk through the subdirectories and remove some of the common words.  For example I want 2013 Q1 AEP Earnings Call Transcript.txt would become 2013 Q1 AEP.txt

The script I wrote is;  FileRename_V1.py

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print (' 1 Working Directory is     %s' %cwd)
print (' ')
sourcedir =  '/Users/Public/Env Defense/Projects/1_Earnings Calls/Quarterly          Earnings Calls/1_IOUs by Quarter/2013 Q1/AAA Done'
os.chdir (sourcedir)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print (' 2 Working Directory is     %s' %cwd)
print (' ')
for dirPath, subdirNames, fileList in os.walk (sourcedir):
    for filename in fileList:

    filename = os.path.join (dirPath, filename)

    os.rename(filename,filename.replace("Earnings Call Transcript", ''))
```

The result is the following error message;

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FileRename_V1.py", line 29, in 
    os.rename(filename,filename.replace("Earnings Call Transcript", ''))

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 
'/Users/Public/Env Defense/Projects/1_Earnings Calls/Quarterly Earnings Calls/1_IOUs by Quarter/2013 Q1/AAADONE\2013 Q1 AEP Earnings Call Presentation.pdf'    ->

'/Users/Public/Env Defense/Projects/1_Earnings Calls/Quarterly Earnings Calls/1_IOUs by Quarter/2013 Q1/AAA DONE\2013 Q1 AEP Earnings Call Presentation.pdf'

I have researched  code to recursively rename files and the code I wrote appears similar to examples that worked.  Any suggestions as to what the problem is and how to correct the script will be much appreciated.

Cheers, BobS

Comment: Shouldn't you first go through all files, store all the ones that need renaming and then rename each of them? Renaming files / directories simultaneously to walking them sounds kinda tricky to me.

Comment: You have a mixture of forward and back slashes in the filepath:

'/Users/Public/Env Defense/Projects/1_Earnings Calls/Quarterly Earnings Calls/1_IOUs by Quarter/2013 Q1/AAA DONE     \ #<< here    2013 Q1 AEP Earnings Call Presentation.pdf'

Comment: The error message is thrown out when os.rename encounters the first file in the first subdirectory.

Comment: the code as written has all forward slashes,  the back slash is introduced by the error message.

Comment: On Python 3.5 you can also use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for recursive searches (but you would have to check if the matches are files or dirs)

Comment: You should check if `"Earnings Call Transcript" in filename` before trying to rename - renaming withuout actually changing the name does not seem like a good idea to me

Comment: @JakubJankowski You can fix that by passing `topdown=False` to `os.walk()`. Then you will not need to rename nodes which you have yet to visit.

Comment: <found this comment regarding[WinError..]   < t's due to the limitations of WinAPI on windows platform. Any file path which exceeds 260 character have to treated in special way. Read this python win32 filename length workaround<

Answer (score 1):

The WinError was caused by the file path exceeding 260 characters.  I edited the directory names to reduce the number of characters and the script worked as intended. It is very helpful to be able to quickly edit the names as I am working with 20 directories each of which contains about 40 subdirectories and each subdirectory contains about 5 files.  Fortunate that someone posted the issue with file path length !!